# How to tell which app can play video / audio?

Tags: android

I want to make a list when it pops up, only shows those app that can play video / audio.
How can I do it?

No particular file to play, just want to launch a media player from the list.
Thanks in advance. Below is the example interested me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible. (Without writting kernel mods)

You can't filter other apps by their sourcecode/binary. 
For what you want to do you would have to determine if an app uses the Media Libs, and even if an app uses them, you can't be sure if the app plays back audio/videos.

You only could list all apps and have a user mark which can do so.

Note: All apps have the possibility to play back audio/video, i think you want those that do so? If you want to see all mediaplayer apps, you should use Intent and MIME.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot from "ClearAudio+" which doesn't seem to be available on google play. It lets me select different media players installed to launch when the earplug is plugged. This is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to share you audio/video file with other app to play it. For that you have to use intent.

Binary data is shared using the [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) action combined with setting the appropriate MIME type and placing the URI to the data in an extra named [EXTRA_STREAM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM). This is commonly used to share an file but can be used to share any type of binary content:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToFile);
shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_t
```

For more details [Documents](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content)

Comment: in fact I just want to launch the media player not to play files.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put intent on the `ListItem` which triggers `application`  abled to open up that kind of `MIME` type files. You can pass dummy `videoPath` as well as `audioPath` with `MIME` type, bundled inside `Intent`.

You need trigger `Intent` on clicking of `ListItem`.

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
                // Add Video & Audio using If- Else or however you like to so
}
});
```

For Video:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newVideoPath));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newVideoPath), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

For Audio:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newAudioPath));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newAudioPath), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

You can also use approach of `CreateChooser`

```
Intent sI = new Intent();
sI.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToFile);
sI.setType("audio/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sI, getResources().getText(R.string.text))
```